# FCM notification, notification click when app is in foreground not background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if(extras != null){
            if (extras.containsKey("URL")) {
                // extract the extra-data in the Notification
                String url = extras.getString("URL");
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
            }
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/");
        }

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Log.d("BODY", messageBody);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

[image]

My apps are using WebView and wish to have some `Notification` function which leads the user to a HTTP page, notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I'm using the Firebase console and sending notification with custom data (refer to image 1).

With the code above, I successfully lead the user to the page when user clicking on the notification if the apps is not open up or in background, but if the apps is opened in the foreground, but it doesn't work.

I believe I should add the `getExtras()` and `extra.getString("URL")` thing other than `onCreate` method, but I have no idea where to add, something like `onResume` or what?

I'm not an Android developer, but I currently have a task which is to complete embedding website inside apps with notifications. Thanks!

Comment: From where you are sending notifications? Firebase console or your own backend?

Comment: @SudipPodder firebase console

Answer (score 0):

i found the solutions, at **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java** add few lines and it work for apps in foreground and background

not sure is this the correct way to do so

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String link = null;

        if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("URL")) {
            link = remoteMessage.getData().get("URL");
        }

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), link);
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String link) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        if (link != null) {
            intent.putExtra("URL", link);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("THE APP NAME");
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```